# Display products based on zipcode without installing any extension

Tags: zipcode

How to display products in home page based on zipcode.

only particular products  will be available for delivery in that particular area(zipcode).How should i do that in magento2?

Answer (score 0):

to do it without external extensions, the only way that I see it now, is creating a custom attribute "zipcode" for your products, set it on your products catalog, and then creating a page with Products widget, filtering by your zipcode attribute, and finally setting this created page as homepage.

But... your product will be with zipcode attribute, what does not make much sense, and you will have to set which zipcode will be rendered on you home page. To get these products dynamically, consider to create your own custom module.